# How to get outlet's data from tableviewcell to tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have several outlets in a custom tableviewcell

```
class ShopTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var orderName: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var specialinstructions: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var shopName: UITextField!


}
```

I have a tableView which is

```
class ConvenienceTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

       override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       }

       func barTapped() {
         // I want to do some validation here, and getting the outlet's data from tableviewcell
       }

}
```

the only way that I could think to get the outlet's data is using `cellForRowAtIndexPath` which are

```
cell.orderName
cell.specialinstructions
cell.shopName
```

But how do i get these outlet's datas and put it in the `func barTapped`?

Comment: When is `barTapped` called?

Comment: When is barTapped() called? Is it when a UITableViewCell is selected? Is it a button in each of your table view cells?

Answer (score 2):

```
let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: requiredRow, inSection: requiredSection)) as? ShopTableViewCell
let orderName = currentCell?.orderName
```

Use this in your `barTapped`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `barTapped` is an action assigned to the button declare the method properly passing the button as parameter. Since the table view cell is usually the super view of the button call `superview` and get the index path. Then you can get the data directly from the model (the data source array) rather then from the view (the cell).

```
func barTapped(button : UIButton) {
   let cell = button.superview as! ShopTableViewCell
   let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way would be to use the data from your DataSource, this is the data that you've provided for your cell!

*For the second part of the answer I assume you can tap the bar from your cell.*

If you would like to do it your way then maybe use a delegate:

```
protocol ShopTableViewCellDelegate {
func barTapped(cellFromDelegateMethod: ShopTableViewCell)
}
```

you can call it in cell like this:

```
@IBAction func someBarTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
   delegate?.barTapped(self)
}
```

and then

```
class ConvenienceTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, ShopTableViewCellDelegate {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   }

   func barTapped(cellFromDelegateMethod: ShopTableViewCell) {
      //here you have your cell
   }

}
```

(remember to set the delegate of this cell at some point in your ViewController!)